# Getting a week before from a specific date

Tags: php, date

Hi im using the following code to get a week before any given date(which comes in my url)

```
$date = $_GET["date"];//23-02-2015
echo date(strtotime($date), strtotime('-1 week'));
```

my expected result is

```
16-02-2015
```

instead, i get something like

```
1425340800
```

can anybody help me to get my expected result

Comment: `date()` function arguments are `date format string`, then the unix timestamp. very easy to check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) `string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )`

Comment: Your question is more about formatting rather than getting the date since the method that you use to get the date is correct. I would rephrase the question by not able to get the correct date format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to the manual of the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions.

```
$date = $_GET["date"];//23-02-2015
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('-1 week', strtotime($date)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<?php

$date = date('d-m-Y'); or //23-02-2015
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('-1 week', strtotime($date)));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
$date = $_GET['date'];
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 week',$date));// 'Y-m-d' is format that returns date in 2014-03-03
```